# Delete duplicates, keeping one of them, grouping by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to delete all the duplicates, all but one, for each of the table ids. Like the following. I need to delete all the duplicates on valueid for 01,02,03...

Original:

```
id      | valueid   |   data
____________________________
01      | 1001      |   datadata1       
01      | 1002      |   datadata2
01      | 1001      |   datadata1
02      | 1323      |   datamoredata123
02      | 1323      |   datamoredata123
03      | 22123     |   evenmoredata
03      | 24444     |   andalsomore
```

Should end like:

```
id      | valueid   |   data
____________________________
01      | 1001      |   datadata1       
01      | 1002      |   datadata2
02      | 1323      |   datamoredata123
03      | 22123     |   evenmoredata
03      | 24444     |   andalsomore
```

Was trying to do it with something like this, but I don´t get how can I group that delete on the id

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT valueid,
       RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY valueid ORDER BY valueid)
   FROM tblvalues
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `id` column to the `PARTITION`:

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT valueid,
       RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER( PARTITION BY id, valueid ORDER BY data)
   FROM tblvalues
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

This way you delete duplicate `valueid` values separately for each `id`. Column `data` determines which duplicates are deleted.

Answer (score 3):

You are pretty close.  You need to change the `partition by` clause.  You want one row per `id`/`valueid` pair, so these should both be in the partitioning clause:

```
WITH todelete AS (
   SELECT valueid,
       RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, valueid ORDER BY data)
   FROM tblvalues
)
DELETE FROM todelete WHERE RN > 1;
```

Comment: Additionally I would include the data column in the order by (after the valueid)...

Answer (score -1):

A very simple way to do this is to add the UNIQUE index in column (valueid). When you write an ALTER statement, specify the IGNORE keyword.

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE tblvalues
ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_name (valueid);
```

This will remove all duplicate rows. As an added advantage, future INSERTs that are duplicates will be erroneous. As always, you can take a backup before running something like this.

Comment: When posting a code answer, it's helpful to the OP to explain the the answer you've provided. In this case, how does this answer help the OP `DELETE` the duplicated rows?

Comment: Thanks for the update, however, if you run that you'll get the error `Unknown object type 'IGNORE' used in a CREATE, DROP, or ALTER statement.
`. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5b2b2efce8a1a834585d54ad1adb237a)

Comment: @Larnu update answer, sorry

Comment: The thing is, this is a already closed database design. Can´t really alter it right now. Thanks for your time and answer, though.